# Properties file resets when adding or updating value (Java)

Tags: java, properties-file

I'm storing user data (nothing important, just user ID and xp amount/level) in a properties file. When using `prop.store(output, comment)` it resets the file completely and then stores the added data. How can I add data without it resetting the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use the `store()` method, it removes the old data and writes the new data.

To prevent this from happening, you must first load your data and then restore it with new data that you want to add.

This code snippet may help you:

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(YOUR_PROPERTIE_FILE));
prop.setProperty(key, value);
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(YOUR_PROPERTIE_FILE), COMMENT);
```

Comment: I am already doing exactly that, and it is still unfortunately resetting all of the data and then adding the new values

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question so that I can help you better?

Comment: I decided to change from using properties files to just using JSON, as the headache this issue was causing me was not worth the trouble. 

My original code was essentially the exact same as your code snippet, just done so 4/5 times over.